# Django admin - disable "edit" for particular model instance

Tags: django

Hi I would like to disable editing (in Django admin) for some model instances acording to model status. If status will be greater than 1 editing will be disabled. I know how to disable that link on the left side but if I set correct URL it could be still editable so this solution is not welcome.

My model:

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
                (1, _(u'p')),
                (2, _(u'w')),
                (3, _(u'l')),
                (4, _(u'p')),
)  

class Ticket(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
   status = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('status'), choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1, editable=False)
```

Answer (score 17):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is not None and obj.status > 1:
            return False
        return super().has_change_permission(request, obj=obj)
```

[See [1]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this thing is the following.

1) Add a template in your template folder named `ticket_change_form.html`

2) Now add following line of code in your template file

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% load admin_modify %}
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% if not read_only %}{% submit_row %}{% endif %}{% endblock %}
```

3) Next add this code into your admin.py file

```
class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'ticket_change_form.html'

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        return TicketForm

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        ticket_object = #get your object here using object_id
        context = {}
        context.update(extra_context or {})
        if not ticket_object.status: 
            context.update({'read_only': True})
        return super(TicketAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url=form_url,
                                                        extra_context=context)
```

That is the simplest way of doing this.